# How can you instantiate or clone/wrap a module in ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, metaclass, eigenclass

I know by default Ruby modules are not instantiate. However I am using a gem with this singleton interface and I need two instances of it since there are two distinct configurations I need. Is there a way to deep clone or instantiate a second object or even wrap it in another close/module and run a second one with all it's methods?

```
module Example
  class << self
    def config
      ....
      Base.name = self.name
      ....
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is `Base`?

Comment: Also, you are always free to `Example.singleton_class.prepend(Module.new { def config; super; Base.name = Other; end })`.

Comment: Base in a class extending ActiveResource, the interface is here https://github.com/chargify/chargify_api_ares/blob/master/lib/chargify_api_ares/config.rb

Comment: FWIW, this question has nothing to do with metaprogramming.

Comment: From my understanding the pattern above uses the metaclass (eigenclass) of ruby to force a singleton pattern on a module, which is why I tagged it metaprogramming :D

Comment: Wouldn't plain #clone just work?

Comment: If you have a class that's utilizing singleton module and you use #instance on it, you can do Class.clone.instance to get another instance. It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Cloning seems to work but the singleton still seems to share the Base::ActiveResource instance. I tried looking for a deep clone, one that would effectively marshal it all but i haven't had any luck.